# SVN Server custom repository 403 forbidden using apache2 on media

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, svn

I am new to ubuntu and trying to setup one svn server on my ubuntu system following this tutorial - http://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-server-on-ubuntu/ where I am trying to set the path of my repository on one of my media. I installed apache2 and svn server and added few line in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf and added

(Vaibhav is my system name and support is my media name which is of ext4 format)
    Alias /svn /media/vaibhav/Support/svn
    
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /media/vaibhav/Support/svn

```
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion Repository"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
</Location>
```

but when I try to access it using the broswer I am getting this message

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /svn/myRepo on this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the apache config for your application, you should specify the access policy. If you want all visitors to be able to access, integrate this into your config. This is a snippet from the app.conf file which is located at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/{app}.conf, or at least that's where it is on Ubuntu.

```
<directory /path/to/app>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </directory>
```